# Spring Cloud Config client sents wrong Basic Auth header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a running Spring Cloud Config client (a Spring Boot 2.0.5 application) on my local machine. It connects to a Spring Cloud Config Server which has Basic Auth enabled. Everything works fine, password is NOT encrypted in the client's config file. So the properties are:

```
spring.cloud.config.username=rxcon
spring.cloud.config.password=rxcon
```

Now when I move the Spring Boot to another machine and configure it to talk to another Spring Cloud Config Server (which has the same credentials rxcon/rxcon) I get a 401 Unauthorized response. So I thought something was wrong with the username password. We checked over and over again and they are correct.

So I increased logging and expected to see the Authorization header to have a value like:

```
Basic cnhjb246cnhjb24=
```

However, the actual header is:

```
Basic cnhjb246Pz91Pz8/aWY/Pz9dBD8eJA==
```

Which is decoded:

```
rxcon:??u???if???]?$
```

So the username is correct, but what's going on with the password?

Note 1: we checked the actual wire value of the header with tcpdump, and yes, it's the wrong one.

Note 2: the value of the Auth header doesn't change if the password is changed.

Note 3: when we log the value of the property (spring.cloud.config.password), we see the correct password (rxcon)

Note 4: Tested with JDK 1.8, 10 and 11

**If I embed a bootstrap.properties in the jar file, will the values be overridden by an external bootstrap.properties?**

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem. Spring Boot DOES allows overriding properties. We had an embedded bootstrap.properties with (development) defaults and overrode it with an external bootstrap.properties file in production. However, ENCRYPTED properties are not overridden by plain text properties. So we had an encrypted embedded spring.cloud.config.password and a plain text version of it in the external bootstrap.properties. **(I said we didn't use encryption, but that was only true for the externalized config file. The embedded file was!)** Once Spring Cloud Config has read all property sources, it searches for encrypted properties (starting with {cipher}), decrypts them and places them in a PropertySource with the highest precedence. Thus the embedded encrypted property effectively shadows the unencrypted externalized one.